# Issue with IE8-9 & "Cross Domain" jQuery/AJAX Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have the following jquery AJAX code, which works great except for in IE 8 & 9. Works ok on 10.

```
 $.ajax({                                    
  url: 'http://www.domain.com/php/dophp.php?make='+ thisValue, data: '', dataType: 'json',       success: function(rows)
```

{

The problem im having is that IE 8 & 9 consider this a "cross domain" request. The url the file is calling from is http://www.domain.com/app. I can change the related security setting within 8 & 9 and it works fine. Why is this considered cross-domain, and how do I fix it? I can move around the called file (/php/dophp.php) to whereever it needs to go.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have a look at this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) on Same Origin policy. Are you sure you're calling the `www.` version from the non `www.` URL or the other way around? You have to make calls on the same host and protocol

Comment: To add to what Ian said, http\https also count as different domains too.

Comment: no matter how you call the page, you are redirected to [http://www.]http://www.domain.com. The code above is [http://www.]http://www.domain.com. So this should fall under Same Origin. @Rory both are http:// no SSL at this point.

Comment: Try making the path relative to the root of the site then, removing the `http://www.domain.com/` part completely

Comment: Just tested it out. Unfortunately, no luck. Still the same issue.

Comment: Something else is going on then. It would be helpful if you provided more context. If you use a domain-less URL like "/php/dophp.php" there should be no cross-domain problem.

Comment: A request won't be sent cross-origin, even if that cross-origin target immediately redirects to a same-origin target.

Answer (score -1):

Ended up using this code sample to address my issue. Thanks to everyone for the help!

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    xhr:  (window.ActiveXObject) ?
    function() {
            try {
                return new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {}
        } :
        function() {
            return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        },
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: post,
    beforeSend: function(){

    },
    success: function(returndata){

    }
});
```

Comment: Preferring the ActiveX object over the native window object is an anti-pattern that breaks in IE Metro mode and when AX filtering is enabled, and it does not solve any problem that you've identified here.